# Highlighting value based on TOC click within BIRT 3.7.2

Tags: jquery, reporting, birt, highlighting

I am constructing a report in BIRT. I am trying to highlight the value that it jumps to when a user clicks one of the groups in the table of contents. It seems like this should be an easy thing to do, but I can't find any documentation for a built-in feature that accomplishes this. I am familiar with the highlighting conditions, but in order to use these I have to be able to access the value that has been clicked in the table of contents and then highlight it if `tableOfContentsItem Equal to currentRowField`. Is this possible without modifying the javascript "onClick" code for BIRT Report Viewer?

EDIT: BIRT Version 3.7.2

Comment: Just to clarify - you want something like "Highlight on Select (or focus)"

Comment: When you click the table of content entry, it jumps to that place in report. It doesn't highlight it in the table of contents, but it may still be a "Highlight on Select". I have looked through the code, but I am not so strong in javascript and am unsure of whether it is a select or click event.

Comment: I am probably not going to be able to help you, but you should include your BIRT version, and how the report is being displayed at run time.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I have added the version number (3.7.2), but I can't do a demo of the report due to the information. It is the same as the default for BIRT report viewer. It functions correctly. When clicking the table of contents, it skips to the correct page number of that item. I am trying to highlight that item when it skips there.

Comment: From your description it sounds like your report is being produced as a PDF with a table of contents.   Is it PDF, word, or how are you displaying it for the client to click on something.

Comment: I believe it is in HTML, but if that is not an option then whatever the default packaging is in the "WebViewerExample" within BIRT runtime. I apologize if that is not the answer you are looking for. This is my first time working with BIRT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the clarification in the the comments.  I can say that if it is possible it would require significant amounts of Java or JavaScript to accomplish.

By the time the report is displayed to the user in the web window, all of the report creation is completed. There are not any easily defined click and/or drag rules in BIRT to have different display changes based on activity after the report is created.

It is likely possible to do as you wish.  If you can write enough Java or JavaScrip you can do pretty much anything in BIRT.  But I think the skills required would be beyond what you or I currently have.